# Question about showing existence

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was attempting the following exercise and saw another proof that I couldn't convince myself was correct.

Exercise: Suppose $v_1,\dots,v_m$ is a basis of $V$ and $W$ is finite-dimensional. Suppose
$T \in L(V, W)$. Prove that there exists a basis $w_1,\dots,w_n$ of $W$ such that
all the entries in the first column of $M(T)$ (with respect to the bases
$v_1,\dots,v_m$ and $w_1,\dots,w_n$) are $0$ except for possibly a $1$ in the first row,
first column

The following was my attempt at showing the existence.

Proof: Clearly the vector $Tv_1$ is linearly independent in range $T$. Using the theorem that a linearly independet list of vectors can be extended to a basis of, we get the basis $Tv_1,w_1,\dots,w_{n-1}$. Then the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $v_1,\dots,v_m$ and $Tv_1,w_1,\dots,w_{n-1}$ has zeroes everywhere in the first column except for a $1$ in the first row, first column. The theorem is obviously true if $Tv_1=0$ as any basis would satisfy the condition.

The following was the proof that I found online.

Proof $2$: If $Tv_1=0$, then any basis $w_1,\dots,w_n$ satisfies the conditions. If $Tv_1\ne 0$, then any basis such that $Tv_1=w_1$ would satisfy the conditions.

My question is: Nowhere does this show the existence of such a basis. Is the proof still correct?. I am having a hard time convincing myself that it is correct.

I know the theorem that a linear map can take on any value on its basis. But we’re already given the linear map. Without actually constructing the basis, how do we know that the map takes on a certain value?

Comment: Minor note: "Clearly the vector $T v_1$ is linearly independent" is true only when $T v_1 \neq 0$. Seems you're aware of the two cases, but the wording is missing there.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof 2 does assume where it says "any basis such that $T v_1 = w_1$" that a basis with that requirement does exist. The reason is exactly the one you used, that we can extend from one non-zero vector $w_1$ to a complete basis of any finite-dimensional space. The author of Proof 2 apparently considered this obvious, but it's also helpful to point out why.

(Likewise, both proofs say in the $T v_1 = 0$ case that any basis of $W$ satisfies the condition, but that still leaves knowing that some basis of $W$ exists. In this case, that's just in the definition of "finite-dimensional".)